# Symfony2 Object of class could not be converted to string error on the simplest code

Tags: php, symfony

I have the most simplest code ever, and I cant understand why the hell do I get this error. I just want to create a form to create a new email message... It looks so simple, yet it just doesnt work....

Here is the error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity\Email could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\Digidis\front\app\cache\dev\twig\e4\61\15c5455e50341edc1387cde083d07297f9c2cb3fe9cf4782bd2ed3ead531.php line 172
```

I tried clearing my cache.

This is the entity:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: domas
 * Date: 6/10/2015
 * Time: 2:18 PM
 */

namespace MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Mp\CmsBundle\Entity\CmsElement;
use Mp\CmsBundle\Entity\CmsImage;
use Mp\CmsBundle\Entity\CmsImageGallery;
use MediaparkLt\LotteryBundle\Entity\Product;
use MediaparkLt\SkinBundle\Entity\UrlSkin;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity\Email
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="email")
 */
class Email {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string")
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId() {
        $this->id = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

This is the form I want to create:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: domas
 * Date: 6/10/2015
 * Time: 2:51 PM
 */

namespace MediaparkLt\SkinBundle\Form\Type;

use MediaparkLt\MainBundle\Form\Type\TranslatableType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class EmailType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
        $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'));

        $builder->add('content', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Content'));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity\Email',
        );
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

Someone help!

Comment: for investigating purpose try implementing the `__toString()` method in the entity class

Comment: You seem to be trying to render an entity in your templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible problems:

1. As @Gerry suggested in the comment, you might be rendering the entity in your `Twig` template in a manner:

   ```
   {{ email }}
   ```

   and since your `Email` entity **does not** have `__toString` it fails.
2. You `getName()` returns `email`. I believe `Symfony2` has that form type name registered internally for `EmailType`. So, `Symfony` might be thinking you are trying to render internal `EmailType` instead of your own.

   Try changing the name to something like `my_email`.

Hope this helps.